# Typo3 9.5 Powermail - How can I insert dynamic input fields in frontend, using javascript or/and ajax

Tags: input, dynamic, typo3, typo3-9.x, powermail

I`m using Typo3 9.5 with powermail. I want to generate dynamic input fields, based to a selectfield. For example: "How many members you want to register?" Then you get a selectbox, where you can choose from 1 to 10. If you select 10, 9 further new input fields should appear.

How can I solve this? If I do it only with jquery, the input fields arent registered and dont get send to the recepient.

Is there a way to integrate dynamic input fields?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible because it is a security risk. Everbody could inject code in this case an send them to TYPO3 / DB. But there is a extension "Powermail Condition" which can help you solving your problem:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/powermail_cond/

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback. I think youre right regarding send input to the database. I will create the special fields and control them via JavaScript. Many thanks.

Comment: May you want to mark my answer as solution for your question?

Comment: If the field is created via AJAX-Request, it wouldn't be a security issue. TYPO3 should have an AJAX handler to keep changes to the form it previously rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a select box with a max amount of dynamic fields: Why not inserting all of them and change the view via javascript according to the selected value? If you want a dynamic Validation, you have to write that too, like: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/WriteOwnValidators/ServersideValidation/Index.html